# How stream multi playing audio in the same time

Tags: node.js, sockets, audio, stream, real-time

I want to use nodejs to stream multiple audios which is auto playing in the background. Meanwhile, someone could connect to the stream and listen to it. The scenario is like radio station.
I guess i could use websocket to broadcast to the client, but how to pass the playing audio data or is there any module I can use.

Comment: Please show code what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi I don't have code, because I stuck at first step, I have no idea how to get playing audio data.

Comment: we are not your Mother ...  SO is not an advise column ... come back with answerable programming questions where your show your work up front ... people invest time answering questions because we learn from the question and displayed code ... welcome to SO ... to your question anything is possible however goal in programming is efficient use of effort and available resources ... I suggest you put aside your project and write a simple nodejs websocket server which at first transfers text then graduate to having it muck about with binary data ( EG streaming audio )